# unexpected result creating xml doctype

Tags: python, xml

I am creating an xml file and I want to insert the doctype line without having to insert it manually.

I'm using this code:

```
docImpl = minidom.getDOMImplementation()
doctype = docImpl.createDocumentType("root", None, dtdPath)
docXML = docImpl.createDocument(None, "root", doctype) 
docXML.appendChild(docXML.documentElement)
docXML.documentElement.setAttribute("lang", language)
doc=minidom.Document()
Tag = doc.createElement('myTag')
docXML.documentElement.appendChild(testCaseTag)
docXML.writexml(open(xmlFile,"w"), "", "   ", "\n", "utf-8")
```

what I get using this code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE root
  SYSTEM 'path.dtd'>
```

in two lines I want it to be on the same line as: `<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM 'path.dtd'>` 
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I corrected the indentation on `SYSTEM` to what Python 2.7 or 3.4 would write. If you really are seeing that much of an indentation after the newline, feel free to revert, but do add the Python version used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the answer.. I'm using python 2.6 so there is no solution ?

Comment: That version too produces the 2-space indentation. `minidom` is rather... archaic. Why not use the ElementTree API instead?

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `minidom` *always* does; if you set the `newl` argument to `writexml()` to `'\n'`, then the doctype line is wrapped.

There is no way around this feature other than not set the `newl` to `'\n'`.